# Avoid numerous instantiations of "MyObjectX extends AbstractObject" to call every myObjectX.execute() ? Design pattern ?

Tags: java, design-patterns

This may be a weird question.

I'm designing some code... which looks like this for moment :

```
abstract class MyAbstractObject {
  String param ;
  abstract void execute () ;
}

class MyObject1 extends MyAbstractObject {
  String otherParam ;
  void exectute() { // implementation } ;
}

class MyObject2 extends MyAbstractObject {
  void exectute() { // other implementation } ;
}

class useMyObject {
  void thisFunctionUsesMyObjects () {
    MyObject1 obj1 = new MyOject1(param1, param2) ;
    MyObject2 obj2 = new MyObject2(param1) ;
    obj1.execute() ;
    obj2.execute() ;
  }
  void thisFunctionToo () {
    MyObject1 obj1 = new MyOject1(param3, param2) ;
    MyObject2 obj2 = new MyObject2(param3) ; 
    // and we could have some more different MyObjectX as well...  
    MyObject3 obj3 = new MyObject3(param3) ;
    MyObject4 obj4 = new MyObject4(param3) ;

    // with an execution in another order
    obj1.execute() ;
    obj3.execute() ;
    obj2.execute() ;
    obj4.execute() ;
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do such code... considering I can have multiple functions such as thisFunctionUsesMyObjects() running at the same time (so static cannot be a solution).

I don't know why it bothers me... I think it's the fact that both MyObject(1,2) always have the same first parameter, and that both only have their execute() method public and called.

Maybe there is not a better way.

Comment: Please provide the code for the `MyObject1` and `MyObject2` constructors as they seem to play an important role in your question.

Comment: @AdamSiemion: I assume MyObject2 uses its single param for `MyAbstractObject.param`, and MyObject` uses them for MyAbstractObject.Param and `MyObject1.param`. I don't think we need more than that.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is : both objets have a param (and its value) in common. They share a same context for instance at a given time. Yet, all instances of those two objects don't share this same context at the same time. The second param is just to distinguish MyObject1 and MyObject2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you *have to* create new instances of `MyObject` and `MyObject2` because the `execute` methods are not reentrant and and the instances are not reusable.  (And I can't see how it can be any different, given the way you are supplying the inputs for the execute methods via constructor parameters.)

You could improve the code with some rewriting:

```
    MyObject1 obj1 = new MyOject1(param3, param2) ;
    MyObject2 obj2 = new MyObject2(param3) ;
    obj1.execute() ;
    obj2.execute() ;
```

could be written as:

```
    new MyOject1(param3, param2).execute();
    new MyObject2(param3).execute();
```

Then you could refactor:

```
  void thisFunctionUsesMyObjects () {
    MyObject1 obj1 = new MyOject1(param1, param2) ;
    MyObject2 obj2 = new MyObject2(param1) ;
    obj1.execute() ;
    obj2.execute() ;
  }
  void thisFunctionToo () {
    MyObject1 obj1 = new MyOject1(param3, param2) ;
    MyObject2 obj2 = new MyObject2(param3) ;
    obj1.execute() ;
    obj2.execute() ;
  }
```

becomes:

```
  void thisFunctionUsesMyObjects () {
    doIt(param1, param2);
  }

  void thisFunctionToo () {
    doIt(param3, param2);
  }

  private void doIt(p1, p2) {
    new MyOject1(p1, p2).execute();
    new MyObject2(p1).execute();
  }
```

Obviously, the benefits increase the more instance of this pattern you have.  OTOH, if the pattern is not as consistent as your example shows, the refactoring may be more complicated.

Comment: Ok. Well, I should have specified that thisFunctionToo() could use MyObjects differently. I can't refactor in a doIt() this way. But rewriting into new MyObject(param).execute() is cool. Basically, I used a template method pattern. And I wondered if another pattern would be better considering that there is only the execute() method that will be called in those objects, and the only reason to instantiate them is to call that method (as well as giving the useful parameters for the execution).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could see to clean up this code, is to introduce a [Factory Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to your code. That will split up the object creation code and the object use code, and it will clean your code up a lot.

**For example**

```
abstract class ObjectFactory
{

    // Here I'm using Constants, but using enum types is the standard practise.
    public final static int OBJECT_1 = 1;
    public final static int OBJECT_2 = 2;
    // Examples.

    public static Object getInstance(int discriminator)
    { 
          // I'm sure you can guess the rest.
    }
}
```

Comment: An enumeration would be safer for the constants, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by refactoring the common code into a seperate method and then use it in your other methods:

```
class useMyObject {
    private void useMyObjects(TypeOfParam1 param1, TypeOfParam2 param2) {
        MyObject1 obj1 = new MyOject1(param1, param2);
        MyObject2 obj2 = new MyObject2(param1);
        obj1.execute();
        obj2.execute();
    }

    void thisFunctionUsesMyObjects () {
        useMyObjects(param1, param2);
    }

    void thisFunctionToo () {
        useMyObjects(param3, param2);
    }

    // and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat yourself:

```
class useMyObject {

  private void executeMyObjects(Param1Type param1, Param2Type param2)
  {
    MyObject1 obj1 = new MyOject1(param1, param2) ;
    MyObject2 obj2 = new MyObject2(param1) ;
    obj1.execute() ;
    obj2.execute() ;
  }

  void thisFunctionUsesMyObjects () {
      executeMyObjects(param1, param2);
  }
  void thisFunctionToo () {
    executeMyObjects(param3, param2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more concrete examples of specific problems, it's hard to make very specific design pattern recommendations.  But one thing you might consider is extracting a method to which you can pass a list or array of these objects in the order you want them executed: like

```
public void executeAll(MyAbstractObject ... objects) {
    for (MyAbstractObject object: objects)
        object.execute();
}
```

Then the functions you have can be written more concisely:

```
void thisFunctionUsesMyObjects () {
    executeAll(new MyObject1(param1, param2), new MyObject2(param1));
}

void thisFunctionToo () {
    executeAll(new MyObject1(param3, param2), new MyObject3(param3), new MyObject2(param3), new MyObject4(param3));
}
```

You could in fact take this a bit further, applying the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to create an object with an `execute()` method that calls all the `execute()` methods in the right order.

This of course does *not* reduce the number of instantiations...